# DEBUG HELP: Flutter StatefulWidget doesn't maintain state(s) after scrolled out of view

Tags: scroll, persistence, state, flutter

I'm playing around with a simple app to learn Flutter. This is the structure of the UI:

`app -- MaterialApp -- HomeScreen (stateful)
                    |- ListView -- PlaceWidget (stateful)
                                |- ListTile`

The PlaceWidget object basically builds and returns a ListTile; its only additional duty is to keep track of the `favorited` state and builds the UI of the ListTile accordingly.

The source code is [here](https://gist.github.com/veltall/999f48a7e9191bc7fae2c1f2e621f970), including two files:

- `main.dart` for the entire app, and
- `places.dart` for the http request

This is how the app behaves: https://gfycat.com/FineBelovedLeafhopper

---

On the surface, it looks as though the states of the objects are lost when scrolled out of view, but a bit of debug logging tells me otherwise.

Suppose I favorite **Oto Sushi** then scroll it off-screen but keep a pointer to the state object, the object's `favorited` state will still be `true`. The object itself (of class `_PlaceWidgetState`), however, is reported to be `defunct, not mounted`.
I can no longer interact with that object. If I tap **Oto Sushi** one more time, it'll create a new state object and set that object's `favorited` state to `true` just like before.

As long as I do not scroll **Oto Sushi** off-screen, I can unfavorite it and things behave normally.

I managed to find similar problems with `TextInputField` and `ExpansionTile` (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803911/expansiontile-doesnt-keep-state)), but I have no idea how to translate the solutions to those problems to this one.

Comment: It's not rendered when it's out of view, therefore doesn't exist and has no state to maintain. You need to maintain the state yourself.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you clarify a bit more on how I should achieve that? When it scrolls back into view, does its `build()` function get called again?

I realize that I can simply keep a variable in a higher scope to keep track of the states, I'm just wondering if there are "good code" standard solutions.

Comment: Sure, `build` will be called again. `build` will usually also be called while it's visible. I haven't investigated this in a while, but if it loses state, `initState` should also be called when it is rendered again when it becomes visible.

Comment: Thanks! I cooked up a dirty solution with a static variable in `MyApp` scope to keep track of the states and check the state in the `build()` method; it's working correctly now. If you have advice on how to do this cleanly, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: https://medium.com/@mehmetf_71205/inheriting-widgets-b7ac56dbbeb1 might be interesting to you. Redux is also often used to maintain state, commonly together with InheritedWidget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, architecture discussions aside, the cause of your problem is in how you are constructing the `State` objects.  By passing the data through the constructor you are ensuring that every time your widgets are rebuilt, their state is reset.

```
 class PlaceWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlaceWidgetState createState() {
    return new _PlaceWidgetState(place, false); // woops, always unchecked
  }

  final Place place;
  PlaceWidget(this.place, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
}

class _PlaceWidgetState extends State<PlaceWidget> { ... }
```

Instead of doing this, use the `widget` getter inside of your state widget to get access to the `place` member. Also make sure you only initialize your `checked` state inside of the State widget - or get it from some external source here.

```
class _PlaceWidgetState extends State<PlaceWidget> {
  bool _isChecked = false; // only store state in State

  Widget build() {
   final Place place = widget.place;
   // build your stuff.
  }
}
```

Now the reason your widget keeps getting rebuilt is that in a `ListView`, offscreen widgets may be destroyed - it is designed for very large lists.  To prevent this, you can also use the [`KeepAlive`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/KeepAlive-class.html) widget.

Comment: For future reference, in case someone as dumb as I am tumbles across this problem, the full solution includes:

- Keeping track of the state locally inside `_PlaceWidgetState`, and retrieving the state of each widget by
- pulling in the context from an `InheritedWidget`. In Jonah's recommendation, we further update `_isChecked` by calling `inheritedWidget.of(context)` and then access/update the state that `_isChecked` should be